# How to install third party msi or exe or bin first and then when its done, start the main application?

Tags: java, installation, jnlp, izpack

Here is the problem, myapp.jar works and runs. But it has other native dependencies.

- It has other third party libraries dependencies, which need to be installed first in windows and linux/mac depending on the user platform.
- How the 
  third_**party**_will_it_install_or_just_download_only.exe 
  OR 
  third_**party**_will_it_install_or_just_download_only.bin

Can be installed automatically ? They are themselves separate installations also.

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" 
> href="advance.jnlp" >
>     
>     
>       <information>
>         <title>Test</title>
>         <vendor>Testing</vendor>
>         <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/"/>
>         <description>Demo</description>
>         <offline-allowed/>
>       </information>
>       
>     
>       <security>
>         <all-permissions/>
>       </security>
>       
>     
>       <resources>
>         <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/>
>         <jar href="myapp.jar" />
>       </resources>
>     
>       <resources os="Windows" arch="x86"> 
>     
>         <j2se version="1.5+"/>
>     
>         <jar href="third___party___will_it_install_or_just_download_only.exe"/>
>     
>       </resources>
>     
>       <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
>         <j2se version="1.5+"/>
>         <jar href="third___party___will_it_install_or_just_download_only.bin"/>
>       </resources>
>       
>       <application-desc main-class="web.Application" />
>       
>     </jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a demo [here](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

Note: the entry point for the installer must be a .jar, so if you want to launch an .exe or .msi you must create another process from within the .jar

Comment: Ic, you mean on first click i can detect which OS and then based on the OS i have to provide my own package which can install those other type of msi/exe or bin and then finally start my application. Do you mean another process as izpack ?

Comment: Some application i have seen used like zip file is it then only a donwnload ? ex:   <resources>

    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/>

    <jar href="DJSweet-Demo_s.jar"/>

    <jar href="DJSweet_s.jar"/>

    <jar href="DJSweet_s.jar"/>

    <jar href="MozillaInterfaces-1.8.1.3_s.jar"/>

    <jar href="FCKeditor_2.6.3_s.zip"/>

    <jar href="TinyMCE_3.2.1_s.zip"/>

    <jar href="SyntaxHighlighter_1.5.1_s.zip"/>

  </resources>

Comment: @Stackfan, to choose an appropriate installer for your OS you would use [OS-specific resources](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html#resources) in the extension JNLP file.  I don't understand what you mean about izpack.

Comment: 1) If its a Windows i need to install this first ex: http://ylatuya.es/gstreamer-winbuild/doku.php?id=download   2) If its a Mac then i need to install this first ex: http://archive.itee.uq.edu.au/~davel/gstreamer/  3) When those libraries get completely installed then my application can only run.  So to combine them should i use izPack packaging software or i can already use any other jnlp method ?

Comment: @Stackfan, you can pack the exe into a jar, then when the installer runs it can unpack the exe into the temp directory and launch it from there.  You don't need any third-party tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the installers simply do the effect of adding natives to the run-time class-path, then the ExtensionInstallerService will not be required.

In that case, just add the natives themselves to the root of a Jar file for each OS and add references to those Jars into the resources section (suitably partitioned for each OS) as nativelib elements.

---

@finnw  BTW: Nice link to the EIS demo.  I might be biased though - I wrote it.  ;)